# Pass PHP data to Ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using [**this**](http://pastie.org/9684008) script I found off the internet to detect a visitors web browser details.

That script gets run when I send a request via an ajax call.

As you can see at the bottom of the php script, there is an array,

```
  return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
```

and this

```
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser=
 "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . "
 " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];

print_r($yourbrowser);
```

How can I pass each of those variables back to ajax in such a fashion I could do this.

```
$.ajax({                                      
 url: 'analyze.php',    
 data: "active=active",
 success: function(data)
  { 
  var userAgent = data[1];
  var name = data[2];
  var version = data[3];
   $("#div1").html(userAgent);
   $("#div2").html(userAgent);
   $("#div3").html(userAgent);
  }      
});
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: You could encode it as JSON data and return that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode the array as a json object

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

and then the ajax call will look like this:

```
$.ajax({                                      
url: 'analyze.php',    
data: "active=active",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data)
{ 
    var userAgent = data.userAgent;
    var name = data.name;
    var version= data.version;
    ....
}
```

Comment: @SLin Your variable $array, where's that come from? Am I supposed to store the array I posted at the top of my explanation inside $array? 

`$array = 
    array(
    'userAgent' => $u_agent`
etc?

Comment: @AshleyBrown Yes, the array that you get from the script should be $array.

Answer (score 3):

You can echo the data as json:

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Then add `dataType:'json'` and access the properties by name in javascript:

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) { 
    var userAgent = data.userAgent;
    var name = data.name;
    var version = data.version;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add `dataType: 'json'` to the AJAX call for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the php script return an array, have it echo the info like this:

```
echo "$u_agent,$bname,$version,$platform,$pattern";
```

Then convert that to an array:

```
var dataArray = data.split(',');
```

Then you can access each variable like so:

```
var userAgent = dataArray[1];
var name = dataArray[2];
var version = dataArray[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .php file

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Set the header type to json at the top of the file.

echo json_encode($array); // Echo out the array as a json-string.
```

In your ajax success function

```
function (data) {
  var foo = data.bar;
}
```